# Cross-platform shooting script (screenplay) software

Tags: video-editing, productivity

My wife's company needs to do some video for client websites. Her consultants use both Mac OSX and Windows.

I think she ought to start using industry-standard shooting script format. Anything out there that's easy and multi-platform? Free is best, as she has consultants coming and going as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a cross-platform desktop app, then [Celtx](http://celtx.com/) is the best free solution:

[image]

> **Multi-Media Friendly**
>   Celtx helps you pre-produce all types of media - film, video, documentary, theater, machinima, comics, advertising, video games, music video, radio, podcasts, videocasts, and however else you choose to tell your story.
>
> **All In One**
>   Unlike scriptwriting software and sites, you can use Celtx for the entire pre-production process - write scripts, storyboard scenes and sequences, develop characters, breakdown & tag elements, schedule production, and prepare detailed and informative production reports for cast and crew.
>
> **Fully Integrated**
>   Celtx is designed to help your entire production team work together on a single, easy to share project file - eliminating the confusion of multiple project files, and the need for 'paper and binder'.

Commercially, there is [Gorilla](http://www.junglesoftware.com/home/), which is Windows and OS X compatible and has many more features than CeltX and I've heard is very good (but I've never used it).

Comment: Looks great. Have you used it? Stability is important. My wife will hurt me if it crashes a lot. :-) I'll run this and the web-solution past the team.

Comment: Well, I much prefer Scrivener myself, but that is Mac only, so I have run a shared project with my girlfriend and collaborators using celtx without problems. It is a bit slower than my mac native software, but never crashed on me or my girlfriend. I know several colleagues who love it, being open-source and all.

Comment: Yes. I love Scrivener, too. Wish it were cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be writing a script with multiple consultants, etc etc, I strongly recommend [ScriptBuddy](http://www.scriptbuddy.com/products/), a *web-based* scriptwriting software.

For my college final year project, a six-part hour-long-each documentary, the project group used this, and it was great to say the least.

The Basic version is free, but the Pro is pretty worth it too. Check it out.

Comment: Their price remained unchanged. USD$15.50 for 3 months worth of ScriptBuddy Pro access - value beyond belief. :)